# Is this a bug in Dropbox?

Tags: security, dropbox, google-authenticator

I had 2 factor authentication enabled for my Dropbox account using Google Authenticator. I got a new phone and in the Dropbox website, clicked edit 2 factor authentication to bring up a QR code to scan. After scanning the code with Google Authenticator on my new phone, it appeared to work. However the code on my new phone isn't accepted but the one from my old one still works.

If this isn't a bug, how is one supposed to use a new device for authentication? Is it expected that a person save a picture of each QR code they scan for an authenticator?

Comment: [Lost phones, or other issues with two-step verification](https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/364), essentially disable and enabled again with your new device.

Comment: @Seth ya that's what I did, though is this really what they expect?

Comment: Why would having two devices being able to unlock the same account mean it is easily defeated? I'm confused.

Comment: @Seth There is absolutely nothing in the Google Authenticator specifications that state that multiple devices can't have the same authenticator something else is going on.  I have my Google Authenticator duplicated across multiple phones and every single pc I have (WinAuth).  Your barking up the wrong tree the squirrel isn't there